# Laravel : Use Pivot table to get group with their respective roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[image]

I'm trying to get All roles in a user group in eloquent style.

```php
//this function is defined in the ModelUserGroup
public function roles(){
    return $this->hasMany(ModelGroupRole::class, 'group_id','id');
}
```

I'm trying to get all roles like this:

```php
ModelUserGroup::with('roles')->get(),
```

I also tried `->hasManyThrough` but it is not working for me.

I need all roles data like id,name, etc. using with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a `belongsToMany` relationship.

In your UserGroup model.

```php
public function roles()
{
    // Assuming your role model is named ModelRole...
    return $this->belongsToMany(ModelRole::class, 'group_role', 'group_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```php
$group = ModelUserGroup::with('roles')->first();

dd($group->roles); // will be a collection of ModelRole's
```

Answered on my phone so there may be syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) in the many to many section, you have got to define the relationships as the follwing:

in User_Group :

```
 public function roles(){
       return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Pathto\Role', 'group_role','group_id','role_id');
    }
```

in Role:

```
 public function user_groups(){        
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pathto\UserGroup', 'group_role', 'role_id', 'group_id');
    }
```

Edit: `ModelUserGroup::with('roles')->get() should work just fine then.`
(of course, change pathto with your path to the models.)